# How to create a new raster in terra with same NA cells?

Tags: r, raster, na, terra

I need to create some new rasters by assigning values using `z <- rast(x, vals = y)`. I would like the new raster (z) to have NA values at the same location as the old raster (x), but with the newly assigned value(s) (y) in the non-NA cells.

**What is the most efficient way to create a new raster with a matching NA pixels but with new values assigned to the non-NA pixels?**

I don't see any argument to handle NA values listed in the documentation for `rast()`, so do I need to do a two step process where the value is first assigned to all cells and then NAs are transfered from the old raster to new?

In the following example I would like `s` to have the same outline as `r` but have a uniform value of 10 in the non-NA cells.

```
f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r <- rast(f)
s <- rast(r, vals=10) # This fill all rasters cells, including NAs
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are four ways to do that:

```
library(terra)
f <- system.file("ex/elev.tif", package="terra")
r <- rast(f)

s1 <- classify(r, cbind(-Inf, Inf, 10))
s2 <- init(r, 10) |> mask(r)
s3 <- ifel(is.na(r), NA, 10)
s4 <- r * 0 + 10
```

I would expect approach 1 and 4 to be the most efficient.

Comment: For those interested in efficiency, using both `Sys.time()` and the microbenchmark package, showed `classify()` was the fastest, followed by the multiplication method, then `init()` and `ifel()`.